# Setting NOPASSWD for a user still promts for a password

Tags: centos, sudo

I am trying to set up an ansible user following a tutorial. They set NOPASSWD to ALL for the ansible user, which allowed them to `-become` root whenever they needed with no password involved.

I tried to do the same and am long unable to get the same result. Running CentOS 8, the following lines from visudo file:

```
## Same thing without a password
%wheel          ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL
ansible         ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL
cloud_user      ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL
```

I'm using cloud_user for login since root login is restricted, but I still need root to install software through ansible. I surfed the internet about the order of the users in the list, but as you can see the cloud_user is the last one and is never mentioned again in the file. I assume that should allow me to use root on it without password.

The issue is that cloud_user is still prompted for password in sudo commands, and ansible says "Missing sudo password".

`sudo -ll` output:

```
Sudoers entry:
    RunAsUsers: ALL
    Options: !authenticate
    Commands:
        ALL

Sudoers entry:
    RunAsUsers: ALL
    Options: !authenticate
    Commands:
        ALL

Sudoers entry:
    RunAsUsers: ALL
    Options: !authenticate
    Commands:
        ALL

Sudoers entry:
    RunAsUsers: ALL
    Commands:
        ALL

Sudoers entry:
    RunAsUsers: ALL
    Commands:
        ALL

Sudoers entry:
    RunAsUsers: ALL
    Commands:
        ALL

Sudoers entry:
    RunAsUsers: ALL
    Commands:
        ALL

Sudoers entry:
    RunAsUsers: ALL
    Commands:
        ALL

Sudoers entry:
    RunAsUsers: ALL
    Commands:
        ALL

Sudoers entry:
    RunAsUsers: ALL
    Commands:
        ALL

Sudoers entry:
    RunAsUsers: ALL
    Commands:
        ALL

Sudoers entry:
    RunAsUsers: ALL
    Commands:
        ALL

Sudoers entry:
    RunAsUsers: ALL
    Commands:
        ALL

Sudoers entry:
    RunAsUsers: ALL
    Commands:
        ALL

Sudoers entry:
    RunAsUsers: ALL
    Commands:
        ALL
```

`sudo -l -U cloud_user` output:

```
Matching Defaults entries for cloud_user on [host name]:
    !visiblepw, always_set_home, match_group_by_gid, always_query_group_plugin, env_reset, env_keep="COLORS DISPLAY
    HOSTNAME HISTSIZE KDEDIR LS_COLORS", env_keep+="MAIL PS1 PS2 QTDIR USERNAME LANG LC_ADDRESS LC_CTYPE",
    env_keep+="LC_COLLATE LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_MEASUREMENT LC_MESSAGES", env_keep+="LC_MONETARY LC_NAME LC_NUMERIC
    LC_PAPER LC_TELEPHONE", env_keep+="LC_TIME LC_ALL LANGUAGE LINGUAS _XKB_CHARSET XAUTHORITY",
    secure_path=/sbin\:/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/bin

User cloud_user may run the following commands on [host name]:
    (ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
    (ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
    (ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
    (ALL) ALL
    (ALL) ALL
    (ALL) ALL
    (ALL) ALL
    (ALL) ALL
    (ALL) ALL
    (ALL) ALL
    (ALL) ALL
    (ALL) ALL
    (ALL) ALL
    (ALL) ALL
    (ALL) ALL
```

`sudo cat /var/log/secure | grep cloud_user` output:

```
Aug 27 13:23:11 localhost sshd[6222]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user cloud_user by (uid=0)
Aug 27 13:23:40 localhost sudo[6270]: cloud_user : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/cloud_user ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/ls /root
Aug 27 13:23:40 localhost sudo[6270]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by cloud_user(uid=0)
Aug 27 13:24:03 localhost sudo[6291]: cloud_user : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/cloud_user ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/cat /var/log/secure
Aug 27 13:24:03 localhost sudo[6291]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by cloud_user(uid=0)
```

Comment: What is the EUID (The Efective User ID)?  Is it `cloud_user` ?

Comment: Does `cloud_user` have the same uid as any other user?

Comment: @ImHere UID and EUID are the same and are 1001. Same for other users, they increment by 1 starting 1000.

Comment: Can you post `id` output? Are you sure this extract is actually used by sudo?

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov `sudo id cloud_user` returns `uid=1001(cloud_user) gid=1001(cloud_user) groups=1001(cloud_user),10(wheel)`. The server is basically empty, I just rented this machine from Linux Academy, I believe it should be quite straightforward but I struggle to get it working.

Comment: A later entry for group wheel (%wheel...) will override your user-specific entry. Put it at the end. Use `sudo -ll` when logged in as cloud_user to see what it says.

Comment: @meuh Got you. I updated the question with `sudo -ll` output. Looks like some entries are still set to "authenticate", I am not sure what I am looking at exactly, though.

Comment: That `sudo -ll` output is a little long. I was expecting only one or 2 "stanzas" to match for your user; you would need the `Options: !authenticate` one to be last. Do you have lots of files in `/etc/sudoers.d/` ?

Comment: @meuh only 1 file: 90-cloud-init-users. Inside rules for centos and clous_user users. centos user has fields with NOPASSWD, cloud_user does not.

Comment: Your sudo either doesn't see your files or works weirdly. Please post the output of `sudo -l -U cloud_user` while running it under root.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov done. Looks similar to the last one.

Comment: You've got too many lines in output. :-( Something seems wrong. Here's what I see: `User birdie may run the following commands on localhost:
    (ALL) ALL
    (ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL` That's it.

Comment: Could you find what was logged in `/var/log/secure` when you tried `sudo` as `cloud_user` and add the entries to the question?

Comment: @sborsky Added logs for cloud_user to the question. There were more but they are probably for ssh authentication.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I just created a brand new machine and it came with the same number of lines except the first 3. There are a bunch of `(ALL) ALL` and that's it. I am not sure what that means, and googling this is painfully difficult...

Comment: CentOS has recently become a rolling distro, you might as well try something stable e.g. RedHat 8 (which is free for personal use) or CentOS 8 stable RHEL based alternatives.

Comment: I've just tested vanilla RHEL 8.4 and everything works as expected. You have a weird sudo configuration probably inherited from your hosting provider.

Answer (score 2):

If multiple configuration lines match to the `cloud_user` and the command requested, then the last line wins. The line in `/etc/sudoers.d/90-cloud-init-users` that matches `cloud_user` without `NOPASSWD` is overriding your line that includes the `NOPASSWD`.

The contents of `/etc/sudoers.d` are included in the main `sudoers` configuration at the point of the `#includedir /etc/sudoers.d` or `@includedir /etc/sudoers.d` directive (correct syntax depends on version of `sudo`). The ordering of the configuration lines is important: you could, in turn, use `visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/91-my-customizations` to add your sudoers lines to take effect *after* the ones made by `cloud-init`.

Also, check `/etc/sudo.conf` for possible plug-ins or alternative configuration sources. A cloud provider may have added some customizations of their own to make sure *their* automation will always be able to do its jobs.

Comment: I see no solution here. Should I clean all invalid lines from 90-cloud-init-users for it to act properly?

Comment: Since **I** don't see the actual contents of your `90-cloud-init-users` file, but only `sudo -l`'s interpretation of it, I cannot say for sure. But it sure looks like that file very likely contains something stupid that needs to be cleaned up. If after doing that `sudo` still behaves strangely, also check `/etc/sudo.conf`.

Comment: Quick question, What does the `90` in `90-cloud-init-users` mean?

Comment: @KevinZhou It's probably there just to define a specific order for reading the files in the directory. Normally files in any drop-in directory are read in classic ASCII alphanumerical sort order, but prefixing a filename with a two-digit number is a common convention to make the desired order explicit. `cloud-init` is probably using the `90-` prefix just to make sure there is plenty of free "space" both before and after it for local customizations, as you could use `00-` to `89-` to place your configuration before cloud-init's settings, or `91-` all the way to to `zz-` to place it after.